# Magento 2.3 "Review & Payments" page not loading

Tags: checkout, magento2.3

I just upgraded from Magento 2.2.3 to Magento 2.3. I am experiencing the following issue:

> During the checkout process, the "**next**" button on the "**shipping**" page
>   does not work. It does not load the "**Review & Payments**" page.

This is the message that I am receiving. Does anybody else have this issue?

Thanks for any help!

[image: "next" button on Magento 2.3 not working]

Comment: You might have a custom module or extension that extends or overrides the shipping page.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback. I will look into that.

Comment: I just enabled the standard flat rate magento shipping option and disabled all other shipping options. But unfortunately it did not solve the problem. Should " disable" the 3rd party shipping extension on the magento backend be enough or would I need the actually disable the module to resolve a possible conflict?

Comment: did you try to disable the module? try to disable the custom module and check if issue will be resolved

Comment: just disabled the custom shipping module but it did not solve the issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: hmmm. check if you have some core modules that has been disabled.

Comment: Madefms, I checked but it does not appear that any core modules are disabled. Right after upgrading from 2.2.3 to 2.3.0 there should not be any core modules that would need to be enabled, correct?

Comment: Latest update on this: I am using "Ultimo" as my theme. When I change it to the magento default theme it solves the issue. So it made me believe that it was theme related. Therefore, I upgraded the Ultimo theme to the latest version (which is supposedly supported by 2.3.0) but I am still having the same problem. Is there anything I can conclude from this?

Comment: I believe the error is not a theme related because the Review and payments page is under a Magento’s core functionality not related to the theme.

Comment: Please dig more on the extensions or modules you have, check on their js files. It might be a validation issue that does not allow the `stepNavigator` to perform `next` function (these codes are found in **`shipping.js`**) once validation is not met or satisfied.

Comment: Again, thanks for the reply. Is there anything I can conclude if the problem is resolved if I switch to the default magento theme? In that case could it still be another module this is the problem?